# Count how many records there are for each foreign key, with LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, count, sql-like

[My image, explanation](https://scontent-b-iad.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/10172678_1395295060746783_1728706954_n.jpg)

- I need to count the foreign key that does not exist, as shown in Fig. And containing the letter 'a' in the name of the list.
- I can only count values​​, but no way to specify the names with the letter 'a'.

I'm using for count:

```
SELECT l.identifier AS id, l.name AS listName, COUNT(p.list_identifier)
AS regCount FROM list AS l LEFT JOIN person AS p ON l.identifier = p.list_identifier
WHERE p.list_identifier IS NULL GROUP BY l.name;
```

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [left outer join](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) & COUNT(DISTINCT ...)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.identifier) AS regCount
FROM list AS l LEFT OUTER JOIN person AS p ON l.identifier = p.list_identifier
WHERE l.Name LIKE '%a%'
```

Comment: I'm using, but wanted to filter only the names containing the letter 'a' in the same query.

Comment: Ok Got it.  Left outer join. I'll try. Thank you.

Comment: You have an example query to show me to make selection of both cases? I can not.

Comment: @FerzinhaFil Oh, sorry, I didn't completely understand what you were asking for.  Updated my answer.

Comment: No problem sweetheart @Joseph . It worked here, thank you very much. Saved me. =)))